# Traveling a few days before expiry of a Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a Schengen visa which is expiring on February 29th. I have plans to travel to Sweden on the 25th of February.

Is it OK to travel just 4 days before the visa expires, or will there be any issues?

Comment: How long do you want to stay in the Schengen area?

Comment: Do you have a return flight booked before 29/02?

Answer (score 2):

Not a problem as long as you got return ticket before 29/02 24:00.

Just check if your visa has **"Last date to enter"**, if there is no such condition, then you can enter until the visa expiry date.